# Ubuntu is not loaded after full disk encryption

Tags: grub-efi

I am beginner with Linux.
I followed that guide to encrypt disk and install Ubuntu 19.10 from USB https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019
I didn't have errors following those steps. These are my partitions in GParted

[image: egparted]

When I reboot my computer I am offered to type in passphrase.
But after I've typed I have only GRUB message that Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported....
Could you please help what can be wrong? It looks like GRUB cannot decrypt partitions...
[image]

Comment: @user68186 `ls` showed me (proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've resolved that issue. Unfortunately I can't answer what was the root cause. I took another USB drive and performed all steps again from the link in my first post. It works correct now. So it looks like my first USB drive is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may occur after entering an incorrect password.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1093953)

Comment: The question is "what can be wrong?". The answer is "the entered password can be wrong". What's wrong here?